# Angular flex not hiding divs

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I have 3 divs that should either show or hide based on different screen sizes however 2 divs are not hiding even though I set them to hide at 1440px width. i.e in the first div, I specify that the second and third div should not show yet they do still show.

Here is my code

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxShow.gt-xl fxHide.gt-md fxHide.gt-sm fxLayoutAlign="start">
  big
</div>

<div fxLayout="column" fxHide.gt-xl fxShow.gt-md fxHide.gt-sm fxLayoutAlign="start">
  medium
</div>

<div fxLayout="column" fxHide.gt-xl fxShow.gt-sm fxLayoutAlign="start">
  small
</div>
```

Here are the custom breakpoints that I am using

```
  'xs': 'screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 575px)',
  'gt-xs': 'screen and (min-width: 576px)',
  'sm': 'screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px)',
  'gt-sm': 'screen and (min-width: 768px)',
  'lt-sm': 'screen and (max-width: 575px)',
  'md': 'screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)',
  'gt-md': 'screen and (min-width: 980px)',
  'lt-md': 'screen and (max-width: 767px)',
  'lg': 'screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1099px)',
  'gt-lg': 'screen and (min-width: 1100px)',
  'lt-lg': 'screen and (max-width: 979px)',
  'xl': 'screen and (min-width: 1100px) and (max-width: 1439px)',
  'gt-xl': 'screen and (min-width: 1440px)',
  'lt-xl': 'screen and (max-width: 1099px)'
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is fxLayout working fine in other case?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I should not specify every other width I want to hide. I can simply just use `fxHide` and then for the width I want to show I can just specify that as I currently do.

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxShow.gt-xl fxHide fxLayoutAlign="start">
  big
</div>

<div fxLayout="column" fxHide fxShow.gt-md fxLayoutAlign="start">
  medium
</div>

<div fxLayout="column" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm fxLayoutAlign="start">
  small
</div>
```